# Vue js: function remove not working properly in my code

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have code below in Vue js that shows Categories from API and whenever i click on any of them it add it to the array AddCategory and post it to API, also i've implemented button Removeall that whenever i click on it, it remove all the selected categories in array (it will empty the array) and it works fine. my problem is when i want to click again on the selected single category (in function remove below) it's not poping it up from array however it pushed it twice, any help?

```html
<template>
  <b-row class="categories-row">
            <div
              class="categories"
              v-for="(category, index) in categories"
              :key="index"
              @click="Add(category._id, index)"
              :class="[selectedIndex.includes(index) ? 'green' : 'gray']"
              required
            >
              {{ category.category_name }}
            </div>
          </b-row>

</template>


export default {
  
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [],
      selectedIndex: [],
      AddCategory: [],
     

      posts: {
        description: null,
        questionTitle: null,
        categories: null,
        
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    Add(AddCategory, index) {
         
  if (this.selectedIndex.includes(index)) 
        this.Remove(index); 
      else
      this.selectedIndex.push(index);
      this.AddCategory.push(AddCategory);
    },
      Remove(index) { //not working
      this.selectedIndex.splice(this.selectedIndex.indexOf(index),1);
    },


    RemoveAll() {
      this.AddCategory = [];
      this.selectedIndex.splice(this.AddCategory);
    },}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Remove(index) { 
      this.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex.filter((item)=> item !== index) ;      
}
```

Edited:

@sara97 maybe you need remove it from this.AddCategory too.

Edited:

@sara97 and because it runs "this.AddCategory.push(AddCategory);" everytime. use {} in if and else.

```
  Add(AddCategory, index) {
   if (this.selectedIndex.includes(index)) {
        this.Remove(AddCategory,index); 
      }else{
      this.selectedIndex.push(index);
      this.AddCategory.push(AddCategory);}
    },

  Remove(AddCategory,index) { 
      this.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex.filter((item)=> item !== index);
      this.AddCategory = this.AddCategory.filter((item)=> item !== AddCategory)
    },
```